# Manipulating a list of lists multiple times in order

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to alter a list of lists in multiple ways by using a function (as I will have more than one list of lists).

I know how to change something once, but how do  I do more than that? I get the error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

I understand that the error essentially means (whatever I'm trying to use  .insert() on is not a list) but I don't quite understand *why* it's not a list...

See my code below:

This works and gives me the desired output

```
list_of_list3 = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
list_to_add = ['Z', 'X', 'Y']

for list_position in range(len(list_of_list3)):
    original_list = list_of_list3[list_position]
    element_to_add = list_to_add[list_position]
    original_list.insert(0, element_to_add)

print(list_of_list3)
```

This will give me what I want:
[['Z', 'a', 1], ['X', 'b', 2], ['Y', 'c', 3]]

However, what I need is a function which does more than one thing at once. I am trying the code below:

```
def output_function(add_list, list_of_list): 
    for list_position in range(len(list_of_list)):
        list_within_list = cleaned_list[list_position]
        add_element1 = add_list[list_position] # The two lists will always have the same length
        list_within_list = list_within_list.pop() # I want to remove the last element
        list_with_element1 = list_within_list.insert(0, add_element1) # I then want to add a new element 
        list_with_new_list = list_with_element1.insert(0, ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']) #Then I want to add a new list to the beginning of list of lists

new_elements = ['A', 'B', 'C']
original_list_list = [['D', 1, 2], ['E', 3, 4], ['F', 5, 6'] 
output_function(new_elements, original_list_list)
```

My desired output is (ultimately will turn this into a pandas df)
[['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'], ['A', 'D', 1], ['B','E', 3], ['C', 'F', 5]]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having some misunderstanding with the methods you are calling.

Your comments indicate you are going to throw away the popped element, but you are actually throwing away the list, and using the element instead.

These 2 lines:

```
list_within_list = list_within_list.pop() # I want to remove the last element
list_with_element1 = list_within_list.insert(0, add_element1) # I then want to add a new element
```

One way to accomplish:

```
list_with_element1 = list_within_list[:-1]
list_with_element1.insert(0, add_element1)
```

Comment: I see. I was misunderstanding what .pop() did. Thanks!